# const member function modifies static object of own class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, constants

I saw multiple answered questions here about const member function allowed to modify static members. But not sure if my question falls into same category. In my example static member function modifies static object of the class, not static member of the class. Why my example works?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual const Base& fun (const Base& n) const = 0;
};

class Child : public Base
{
    int content;
public:
    Child(int i = 0) : content(i) {}
    const Base& fun (const Base& n) const;
};

const Base& Child::fun (const Base& n) const
{    
    static Child static_child;
    static_child.content = content + static_cast<const Child&>(n).content;
    cout << "static child content is " << static_child.content << endl;
    return static_child;
}

int main() {
    Child c(10);
    Base* b = &c;
    b->fun(*b).fun(*b);
}
```

The output will be

```
static child content is 20
static child content is 30
```

So const function successfully changed Child object. Moreover, on the second call it successfully changed **this** object. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing your code modifies is `static_child` which is a non-const object

Answer (score 3):

> So `const` function successfully changed Child object. Moreover, on the second call it successfully changed **this** object.

Neither call changed `this`. `c.content` remains `10` at the end of the program. The `const` qualification on the member function simply prevents you from modifying non-`mutable`, non-`static` members of the class instance itself. But you're not doing that - you're modifying a member of a local `static`. That's not something that's promised by `const` qualification and is, as you observe in your program, perfectly legal.

Comment: Concerning this change - sorry, typo in main code. Fixed.

Comment: @Bob So... what's your question? Can you fool the compiler into doing questionable things?

Comment: Concerning this change - sorry, typo in main code. Fixed. Now `fun` modifies **this**. I didn't get explanation about const qualification still... `static_child` is object of the class Child? Yes. An object of class Child has non-static member `content` ? Yes. How `content` of static class object is different from `content` in non-static class object?

Comment: In another words, I understand that class instance is static. But non-static member`content` of a static class instance `static_child` still regular non-static member?

Comment: @Bob Yes, but you're not accessing it through `this`. You're accessing it through a non-`const` interface.

Comment: `b-> fun(*b).fun(*b);`  First `fun` call returns reference to `static_child`. Second fun call runs for `this` equal to `&static_chilld`. All objects of class Child have a regular, non-static member `content`. Second call modifies `static_child.content`, which is actually is `this->content`. In the end, we have const function `fun` modifying a regular non-const member of class Child. Which looks like a contradiction to me. I thought `fun` guaranteed not to change `content`. Moreover, I thought `fun` guaranteed not to change `content` neigther in `this` nor in any other Child object.

Comment: `this` is not the same as `&static_child` on the second call.  `this` has the type `const Child*`, but `&statc_child` has the type `Child*`.  It is not `const`, and is therefore fine to change.  It doesn't matter that it actually points to the same object as `this`.

Comment: @Bob Yes, but you're not explicitly modifying anything in `this`. You're modifying via `static_child`, which is non-`const`. The language doesn't prevent you from doing questionable things if you try really hard to do them.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now. Const function monitors access - and will fail to compile if change is attempted - via **this**. It doesn't care if some other pointer or reference actually refers to the same object as **this**.